# Buscar registros de determinado dia da semana

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Pessoal tenho o seguinte select

```
set temp = Conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_estacionamento ORDER by id asc")
```

Tenho uma tabela chamada data aonde eu registro o dia do cadastro da informação, gostaria de saber como eu posso exibir apenas resultados registrados nos domingos.

Obrigado :D

Answer (score 2):

Pessoal consegui fazendo uns testes aqui com a seguinte query

```
WHERE WEEKDAY(DATA) = 1
```

:D

Comment: desta forma exibe resultados cadastrados no domingo (1 domingo, 2 segunda....)